# Insert into in python cql throwing syntax error

Tags: python, cassandra, cqlsh

I tried creating table in cassandra using the following code in python

```
CREATE TABLE videos(
id uuid,
added_date TEXT,
title text,
PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

I tried to insert values using the following code

```
INSERT INTO videos(id,added_date,title)
VALUES(uuid(),"2014-01-29","Cassandra History");
```

I am getting the following error

```
SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 2:45 no 
viable alternative at input ',' (...,title)VALUES(uuid(),["2014-01-2]9",...)">
```

Comment: Try using single quotes around your string values.

Comment: @Ralf Thank you its working perfectly.I did not expect that the error will be due to quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Ralf double quotes caused the error.When single quotes is used around the string it worked perfectly.

```
INSERT INTO videos(id,added_date,title)
VALUES(uuid(),'2014-01-29','Cassandra History');
```

Comment: That helped me too.